# my text-to-speech android app stopped working when i put it in a tab 

Tags: android, tabs, text-to-speech

I have a text-to-speech app and it works perfectly. thing is I have to put it in a tab, and the tabs works fine. But when I put the tts inside the tab, it doesn't work anymore. I already changed class name, layout to view and package, everything else's pretty unchangeable except the variables of course. Layout's fine. And unluckily I really have to put it in a tab. but the worst part is that it doesn't show any errors. Even try catch can't catch anything. So I suppose it's a kind of a logical error, and it sucked all the logic in my head. Lol. I checked the main activity, where this activity is called, and manifest, they're clean. So, here's the code:

```
package leytocz.add.andriod;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class nptab extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nptab);
        tts=new TextToSpeech(this,this);
        btnSpeak=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        txtText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }
        });
    }
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS","This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initialization Failed!");
    }
}
private void speakOut() {
    String text=txtText.getText().toString();
    tts.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
}
```

Comment: doesn't anyone have the answer? :(

Comment: I did something similar and had my TabHost create the tts and had a static get method for other activities to use this tts-object. Don't know if this is best practice but works flawless.

Comment: Sir, correct me if I'm wrong, you're tts declarations are in the TabHost, not in the activity itslef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.

```
static TextToSpeech mTTS;
```

onCreate():

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

onActivityResult:

```
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE && !mTTSInitialized) 
    {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) 
        {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, (OnInitListener) this);
            if (mTTS!=null)
                mTTSInitialized = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
```

Getter:

```
public static TextToSpeech getmTTS() {
    return mTTS;
}
```

All of this is placed in the TabHost itself.

Comment: wait, could you explain it first please. i don't quite understand your codes.

Comment: it's far from how i called tts. i'm not familiar with it. please explain. thank you.

Comment: Well, you create a class variable of Type TextToSpeech which is a member of the class containing your TabHost. Usually such variables are placed between your class declaration and the activities onCreate() method.
Then in onCreate() you create an Intent to check the availability of TTS on the phone.

Comment: In the `onActivityResult()` method you finally initialize the TTS-variable declared in the first step.

For use in other activities you create a getter-method in the class containing the `TabHost` which just returns the TTS-variable.

In the `Activity` where you want to use TTS you call the `TabHost`'s getter, e.g. `TabHostClass.getmTTS().speak("Spoken Text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`

Comment: Have you been able to implement your Tab independent TTS?

Comment: can't make your code work man, sorry. maybe i'm just too noob. lol. but thanks for the idea of setting the tts declarations in the main activity. will try it now using my own codes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to write this much code in your activity just write this line alone,i also faced this problem finally i got this solution.

Change this one

```
tts=new TextToSpeech(this,this); --this is your code
```

You change like this

```
tts=new TextToSpeech(getParent(),this);
```

It will work perfectly for me